# Copy Files From List Python

Tags: python, wxpython, cp, shutil

Im making a small python program to copy some files. My filenames are in a list "selectedList".

The user has selected the source dir "self.DirFilename" and the destination dir "self.DirDest".

I'm using cp instead of shutil because I've read that shutil is slow.

Heres my code:

```
for i in selectedList:
    src_dir = self.DirFilename + "/" + str(i) + ".mov"
    dst_dir = self.DirDest
    r = os.system('cp -fr %s %s' % (src_dir, dst_dir))
    if r != 0:
        print 'An error occurred!'**
```

I would like the copy to search the source directory for the given filename and then recreate the folder structure in the destination as well as copy the file.

Any suggestions would be helpful (like any massively obvious mistakes that i'm making)- its my first python programme and I'm nearly there!

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: To avoid having problems and security issues with funny unescaped characters (such as whitespace), do this: `r = subprocess.call(('cp', '-fr', src_dir, dst_dir + '/'))`

Comment: FYI `shutil` is slow for copying because its buffer size is only 16K. A larger buffer size can make a big difference, according to multiple sources (e.g. http://blogs.blumetech.com/blumetechs-tech-blog/2011/05/faster-python-file-copy.html). For recursive copies it's not easy to change the `shutil` buffer size. See the link above for an alterative implementation Probably the huge difference is related to different disk seeking patterns.

Comment: It's not obvious for me what the question is here.

Comment: Thanks pts, I'll look into both these.

Comment: I want to search a directory for the file specified in the list. The found file may be a few folders deep into the directory. Once the file has been found I want to copy the file and its folder structure to the destination directory. My current code will only find in one directory and copy to another. Does this make sense?

Comment: Instead of `print 'An error occurred!'`, you may want to raise an exception and thus stop further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this could do the trick. Of course you may want to use something ore advance that os.system to call cp.

```
import os

for r, d, f in os.walk(self.DirFilename):
    for file in f:
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if ".mov" == f_ext:
            if f_name in selectedList:
                src_abs_path = os.path.join(r, file)
                src_relative_path = os.path.relpath(src_abs_path, self.DirFilename)
                dst_abs_path = os.path.join(self.DirDest, src_relative_path)
                dst_dir = os.path.dirname(dst_abs_path)
                if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
                    os.makedirs(dst_dir)
                ret = os.system('cp -fr %s %s' % (src_abs_path, dst_abs_path))
                if ret != 0:
                    print 'An error occurred!'
```

Comment: Thanks Zuljin, That worked but only for the first item in the list. Your code is a little advanced for me, I'm going to take some time to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: After making sense of your code I'm finding one problem with it. It works perfectly for me but then gets stuck after copying 1 file. I'm getting this error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gavinhinfey/Desktop/ALEXAFROMEDL.py", line 119, in DoTheCopy
    src_abs_path = os.path.join(r, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: Yes, because you are overwriting the variable r with the return value of os.system. Use a different variable name down there.

Answer (score 0):

See http://blogs.blumetech.com/blumetechs-tech-blog/2011/05/faster-python-file-copy.html for a pure Python implementation of the recursive copy.

You can use `os.walk` to find the file you need:

```
def find_files(...):
    for ... in os.walk(...):
        if ...:
            yield filename

for name in find_files(...):
   copy(name, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
for fname in selectedList:
    filename = str(fname) + '.mov'
    found = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.DirFilename, filename))
    found.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(self.DirFilename, '**', filename)))
    found = [(p, os.path.join(self.DirDest, os.path.relpath(p, self.DirFilename))) for p in found]
    for found_file in found:
        # copy files however
        #r = os.system('cp -fr %s %s' % found_file)
```

Comment: found = [(p, os.path.join(self.DirDest, os.path.relpath(p, self.DirFilename))) for p in found]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @GavinHinfey odd, I don't get a syntax error. What part is it complaining about?

Comment: the end of the variable "found" in the line I quoted.

Comment: @GavinHinfey Ah, found it, it was a missing paren on the line before, fixed